# Hibernate Lazy Initialization exception even using Join Fetch in HQL queries

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I want to initialize a collection with lazy fetch mode and use Join Fetch in my queries but I some times(not always) face with lazy initialization exception ???

> org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize
>   a collection of role: xxx.entity.Product.producerEntities, could not
>   initilaize proxy - no session ...

for example this query:

```
"select p from Product p left join fetch p.producerEntities"
```

and my persistence class:

```
    class Product
    {
        Set<Producer> producerEntities = new HashSet<>();
        ....
        @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinColumn(name="pid")
        public Set<Producer> getProducerEntities(){
         return producerEntities;
         }
    ....

}
```

I don't understand what is the problem?

Comment: default fetch type for @OneToMany is lazy.

Comment: I know Angad Bansode, for clear I write fetch = FetchType.LAZY.

Comment: can you add an example of when that exception happens? Is that happening while getting some nested element inside `Producer` ?

Comment: you could use Dynamic entity graphs can be the better solution, if you need to define a use case specific graph.If Join fetch is not working.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Problem was from my collection setter and getter methods name. It issolved.

Comment: Could you please elaborate exactly what you had to change.

Answer (score 0):

If join fetch is throwing LIEX then i could suggest use Dynamic Entity Graph, because if you need to define a use case specific graph.

Lets try this one, i did and work for me.

```
public class DynamicEntityGraphDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EntityManager em = HibernateUtil.getEntityManager();
        EntityGraph graph = em.createEntityGraph(Product.class);
        Subgraph itemGraph = graph.addSubgraph("producerEntities");

        Map hints = new HashMap();
        hints.put("javax.persistence.loadgraph", graph);

        Product pro = em.find(Product.class, 1, hints);
        System.out.println("DynamicEntityGraphDemo pro  = " + pro.toString() + 
                 "producer =  " + pro.getProducerEntities().toString());
    }
}
```

NOTE : Dynamic Entity Graph uses LEFT OUTER JOIN while retrieving child entity.
       (Subgraph itemGraph = graph.addSubgraph("producerEntities");)

Answer (score 0):

join fetch p.producerEntities, not p.producer..

Comment: you're right. it is just my syntax error(query work most of the times).

Answer (score 0):

there are many ways to solve, using hibernate properties

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource(); 
    return dataSource;
}

@Bean
public LocalSessionFactoryBean getSessionFactory() throws IOException {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    factoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource()); 

    Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties(); 
    hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans", "true"); 
    factoryBean.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties);
    factoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();

    return factoryBean;
}

@Bean
public HibernateTransactionManager getTransactionManager() throws IOException {
    HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setSessionFactory(getSessionFactory().getObject());
    return transactionManager;
}
```

or you can use

```
org.hibernate.annotations.@Proxy 

@Entity
@Table(name = "ACTOR")
@Proxy(lazy = false)
public class Actor
```

Comment: "hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans" is considered an anti-pattern as is eager loading with n+1 queries. The whole point of FetchType.LAZY and JOIN FETCH is to address this.